# Error- Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: html, reactjs

I am getting an error as:

> Parsing error: Unterminated JSX contents

This is my code:

```
<div class="hero-wrap js-fullheight" style="background-image: url('images/bg_1.jpg');" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-start" data-scrollax-parent="true">
            <div class="col-xl-10 ftco-animate" data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }">
                <h1 class="mb-4" data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }"> Get <br/><span>your Things Done</span></h1>
                <p class="mb-4" data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }">Over 10K People across Sri Lanka
                    <br/><span> are willing to Help you</span></p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no such error, https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tc5cgl . Consider providing a way to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the same error message as in your question, but there is a syntax error in the first `div`. The `style` property is not being specified correctly.

You have `style="background-image: url('images/bg_1.jpg');"` which produces the following error in the console:

> Invariant Violation: The `style` prop expects a mapping from style
>   properties to values, not a string. For example, style={{marginRight:
>   spacing + 'em'}} when using JSX.

The correct syntax for React is `style={{ backgroundImage: "url('images/bg_1.jpg')" }}`

You also are using `class` instead of `className` resulting in this warning:

> Invalid DOM property `class`. Did you mean `className`?

Here is a version of your code with correct React syntax:

```
<div
  className="hero-wrap js-fullheight"
  style={{ backgroundImage: "url('images/bg_1.jpg')" }}
  data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5"
>
  <div className="overlay" />
  <div className="container">
    <div
      className="row no-gutters slider-text js-fullheight align-items-center justify-content-start"
      data-scrollax-parent="true"
    >
      <div
        className="col-xl-10 ftco-animate"
        data-scrollax=" properties: { translateY: '70%' }"
      >
        <h1
          className="mb-4"
          data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }"
        >
          Get <br />
          <span>your Things Done</span>
        </h1>
        <p
          className="mb-4"
          data-scrollax="properties: { translateY: '30%', opacity: 1.6 }"
        >
          Over 10K People across Sri Lanka
          <br />
          <span> are willing to Help you</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit 747xjz1870]